# wrong path using 'require'

Tags: php, filepath

Since moving my website from local to online , I have a path problem using **require**.

I have pages that call **bootstrap.php** like this:

```
require 'inc/bootstrap.php';
```

And **boostrap.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('app_autoload');

function app_autoload($class){
require "class/$class.php";
}
```

This worked well in local.

Now, online, I get the following message:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/website/www/class/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/www/inc/bootstrap.php on line 6

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/website/www/class/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') 
in /home/website/www/class/functions.php on line 6
```

So I thought, I should put an absolute path in **boostrap.php** like this:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('app_autoload');

function app_autoload($class){
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "class/$class.php";
require_once "$path";
}
```

But I get the exact same error.
I dont understand why it is still looking in the /home/website/www/inc/bootstrap.php and not following the absolute path which is /home/website/www/class/functions.php ?

**EDIT:**

After testing the different solutions using absolute pathes, I am still getting the error that "No such file or directory in /home/website/www/bootstrap.php: so it is still looking in the file instead of directory.

Could it be because I am using **a double require**? I first require *boostrap.php* from *description.php* (which works fine) and then I require *class.php* from this *boostrap.php* (which doesent take the absolute path but the path corresponding to the file *boostrap.php* ?

**ANSWER:**

Ok it finally works with this configuration:

First file using require:

```
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__). '/inc/bootstrap.php');
```

and boostrap.php:

```
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__). "/../class/$class.php");
```

Comment: what if you add `/inc/` in your path like so.  `require "inc/class/$class.php";`

Comment: because you call the `require` func in _/home/website/www/inc/bootstrap.php_ Try with `$path = dirname(__DIR__)."/class/$class.php";`

Comment: @michltm note that would be fine to maintain same structure in local and remote. If it is not possible, I suggest you to add path(s) to existing/new config file.

Comment: @michltm I have re-read your error: what is it the path of **executing** script?

Comment: Have you tried: `require './inc/bootstrap.php';`

Comment: thx for answers. cmorrissey: using /inc/ brings to error: Warning: require(/inc/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/www/description.php. (description.php is the page where require boostrap.php is called).
fusion3k: $path = dirname(__DIR__)."/class/$class.php"; gives the exact same error than using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. Ryan Vincent: I kept the exact same working directory than in local and require __DIR__ .'/../inc/bootstrap.php'; gives same error than cmorrissey .OlivierQueen : './inc/bootstrap.php'
gives the same as 'inc/bootstrap.php'

Answer (score 0):

1. As it was said in comments, it is safe to use absolute path instead of 'inc/...', cause it is relative to current class execution path, i.e.:

   ```
   define ('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).'/../');
   ```

   Then use BASE_PATH.{your_path} to access files.
2. I suggest to use require_once to avoid multiple inclusions.

Comment: I tried using dirname(_FILE_)  instead od just 'inc/...' but it doesent change anything on the error message. Using require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../inc/bootstrap.php'; leads to Warning: require_once(/home/website/www/../inc/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/website/www/description.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/website/www/../inc/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/website/www/description.php on line 4.

Comment: now it is clear. Your main script location is /home/website/www/description.php

Comment: Your bootstrap is in /home/website/www/inc/bootstrap.php and in this case, you are trying to locate it is /home/website/inc/bootstrap.php. Solutions: 1. put description.php to subdir of /home/website/www, change BASE_PATH definition to

Comment: dirname(__FILE__).'/'

Comment: please also check .htaccess file in inc dir and inc,bootstrap.php file attributes - probably it forbids reading or executing file